# How to make jQuery UI nav menu horizontal?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, menu

I love the jQuery UI stuff!

I like the navigation menu, but I can't seem to get it horizontal. I've got to be missing something that's a cinch.

Anyone know how to change the CSS? I tried this but it is for an older version and doesn't work, since there is no longer "clear" to keep them on top of each other.

Relevant CSS:

```
.ui-menu { list-style:none; padding: 2px; margin: 0; display:block; outline: none; }
.ui-menu .ui-menu { margin-top: -3px; position: absolute; }
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item { margin: 0; padding: 0; zoom: 1; width: 100%; }
.ui-menu .ui-menu-divider { margin: 5px -2px 5px -2px; height: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; border-width: 1px 0 0 0; }
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a { text-decoration: none; display: block; padding: 2px .4em; line-height: 1.5; zoom: 1; font-weight: normal; }
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-focus,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-active { font-weight: normal; margin: -1px; }

.ui-menu .ui-state-disabled { font-weight: normal; margin: .4em 0 .2em; line-height: 1.5; }
.ui-menu .ui-state-disabled a { cursor: default; }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this:

```
/* Clearfix for the menu */
.ui-menu:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

and also set:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work! I was accidently restricting the width in the html. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This made the list horizontal for me but did not make the hovered buttons vertical. is there a way to position the hovered links? here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/HSHEC/3/

Comment: I think it's more complicated than this. This doesn't quite work with all the standard features of a horizontal menu bar. See my answer below for advice on downloading the jQuery UI menubar widget (not yet bundled with the official jQuery UI download)

Answer (score 28):

I admire all these efforts to convert a menu to a menubar because I detest trying to hack CSS. It just feels like I'm meddling with powers I can't possibly ever understand!  I think it's much easier to add the menubar files available at the [menubar branch of jquery ui](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/menubar).

I downloaded the full jquery ui css bundled file from the [jquery ui download site](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

In the head of my document I put the jquery ui css file that contains everything (I'm on version 1.9.x at the moment) followed by the specific CSS file for the menubar widget downloaded from the [menubar branch of jquery ui](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/menubar)

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.ui.menubar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Don't forget the images folder with all the little icons used by jQuery UI needs to be in the same folder as the jquery-ui.css file.

Then at the end the body I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menubar/jquery.ui.menubar.js"></script>
```

That's a copy of an up-to-date version of jQuery, followed by a copy of the jQuery UI file, then the menubar module downloaded from the [menubar branch of jquery ui](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/menubar)

The menubar CSS file is refreshingly short:

```
.ui-menubar { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding-left: 0; }
.ui-menubar-item { float: left; }
.ui-menubar .ui-button { float: left; font-weight: normal; border-top-width: 0 !important; border-bottom-width: 0 !important; margin: 0; outline: none; }
.ui-menubar .ui-menubar-link { border-right: 1px dashed transparent; border-left: 1px dashed transparent; }
.ui-menubar .ui-menu { width: 200px; position: absolute; z-index: 9999; font-weight: normal; }
```

but the menubar JavaScript file is 328 lines - too long to quote here. With it, you can simply call menubar() like this example:

```
$("#menu").menubar({
    autoExpand: true,
    menuIcon: true,
    buttons: true,
    select: select
});
```

As I said, I admire all the attempts to hack the menu object to turn it into a horizontal bar, but I found all of them lacked some standard feature of a horizontal menu bar.  I'm not sure why this widget is not bundled with jQuery UI yet, but presumably there are still some bugs to iron out. For instance, I tried it in IE 7 Quirks Mode and the positioning was strange, but it looks great in Firefox, Safari and IE 8+.

Comment: +1 CSS hacking is only fun when you don't have a project to finish

Comment: Screwed around for hours trying to get just the menubar JS integrated with the standard jQuery UI, and now your post has gotten things to work. Thanks!

Comment: This works, although I get an error on `select: select` - `Uncaught ReferenceError: select is not defined`

Comment: The menubar branch url https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/menubar is not working. Is there any alternative url.

Comment: The jQuery UI team isn't developing/supporting the menubar widget for now: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/38666403/Menubar

Comment: @Steven is the jQuery UI suite dead?

Answer (score 16):

This post has inspired me to try the jQuery ui menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Bvap/

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-12</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-13</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>


.ui-menu { 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.ui-menu > li { 
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: auto !important;
}
.ui-menu ul li {
    display:block;
    float:none;
}
.ui-menu ul li ul {
    left:120px !important;
    width:100%;
}
.ui-menu ul li ul li {
    width:auto;
}
.ui-menu ul li ul li a {
    float:left;
}
.ui-menu > li {
    margin: 5px 5px !important;
    padding: 0 0 !important;
}
.ui-menu > li > a { 
    float: left;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-icon { 
    margin-top: 0.3em !important;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu .ui-menu li { 
    float: left;
    display: block;
}


$( "#nav" ).menu({position: {at: "left bottom"}});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vapD7/

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-12</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3-13</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>

.ui-menu { list-style:none; padding: 2px; margin: 0; display:block; outline: none; }
.ui-menu .ui-menu { margin-top: -3px; position: absolute; }
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-divider { margin: 5px -2px 5px -2px; height: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; border-width: 1px 0 0 0; }
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a { text-decoration: none; display: block; padding: 2px .4em; line-height: 1.5; zoom: 1; font-weight: normal; }
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-focus,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-active { font-weight: normal; margin: -1px; }

.ui-menu .ui-state-disabled { font-weight: normal; margin: .4em 0 .2em; line-height: 1.5; }
.ui-menu .ui-state-disabled a { cursor: default; }
.ui-menu:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

$( "#nav" ).menu({position: {at: "left bottom"}});
```

Answer (score 5):

I just been for 3 days looking for a jquery UI and CSS solution, I merge some code I saw, fix a little, and finally (along the other codes) I could make it work!

http://jsfiddle.net/Moatilliatta/97m6ty1a/

```
<ul id="nav" class="testnav">
    <li><a class="clk" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="clk" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="clk" href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-12</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Item 3-111</a></li>                         
                            <li><a href="#">Item 3-112</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-1111</a></li>                            
                                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-1112</a></li>                            
                                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-1113</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Item 3-11131</a></li>                           
                                            <li><a href="#">Item 3-11132</a></li>                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>                           
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item 3-113</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-13</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#."> Item 3-21 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#."> Item 3-22 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#."> Item 3-23 </a></li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="clk" href="#">Item 4</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 4-1</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#."> Item 4-11 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#."> Item 4-12 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#."> Item 4-13 </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#."> Item 4-131 </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#."> Item 4-132 </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#."> Item 4-133 </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="clk" href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var menu = "#nav";
var position = {my: "left top", at: "left bottom"};

$(menu).menu({

    position: position,
    blur: function() {
        $(this).menu("option", "position", position);
        },
    focus: function(e, ui) {

        if ($(menu).get(0) !== $(ui).get(0).item.parent().get(0)) {
            $(this).menu("option", "position", {my: "left top", at: "right top"});
            }
    }
});     });
```

CSS

```
.ui-menu {width: auto;}.ui-menu:after {content: ".";display: block;clear: both;visibility: hidden;line-height: 0;height: 0;}.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {display: inline-block;margin: 0;padding: 0;width: auto;}#nav{text-align: center;font-size: 12px;}#nav li {display: inline-block;}#nav li a span.ui-icon-carat-1-e {float:right;position:static;margin-top:2px;width:16px;height:16px;background:url(https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/ui-icons-222222-256x240.png) no-repeat -64px -16px;}#nav li ul li {width: 120px;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}#nav li ul {width: 120px; }.ui-menu .ui-menu-item li a span.ui-icon-carat-1-e {background:url(https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/ui-icons-222222-256x240.png) no-repeat -32px -16px !important;
```

Comment: best solution of all these listed here, by far. Thanks @Moatilliatta

Answer (score 4):

Just think about the jquery-ui menu as being the verticle dropdown when you hover over a topic on your main horizonal menu.  That way, you have a separate jquery ui menu for each topic on your main menu.  The horizonal main menu is just a collection of float:left divs wrapped in a mainmenu div.  You then use the hover in and hover out to pop up each menu.

```
$('.mainmenuitem').hover(
    function(){ 
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-focus');
        $(this).addClass('ui-corner-all');
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-active');
        $(this).addClass('mainmenuhighlighted');
        // trigger submenu
        var position=$(this).offset();
        posleft=position.left;
        postop=position.top;
        submenu=$(this).attr('submenu');
        showSubmenu(posleft,postop,submenu);    
    },
    function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-focus');
        $(this).removeClass('ui-corner-all');
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-active');
        $(this).removeClass('mainmenuhighlighted');
        // remove submenu
        $('.submenu').hide();
    }
    );
```

The showSubmenu function is simple - it just positions the submenu and shows it.

```
function showSubmenu(left,top,submenu){
    var tPosX=left;
    var tPosY=top+28;
    $('#'+submenu).css({left:tPosX, top:tPosY,position:'absolute'});
    $('#'+submenu).show();
}
```

You then need to make sure the submenu is visible while your cursor is on it and disappears when you leave (this should be in your document.ready function.

```
$('.submenu').hover(
            function(){ 
                $(this).show();
            },
            function(){ 
                $(this).hide();
            }
            );
```

Also don't forget to hide your submenus to start with - in the document.ready function

```
$(".submenu" ).hide();
```

See the full code here

http://jsfiddle.net/R4nyn/

Comment: The fiddle is not working (submenus are not shown). `Showsubmenu` call is wrapped in `setTimeout` in the fiddle. If I directly call `Showsubmenu`, then it is working.

Comment: It will work in IE7 also.....Good job...direct call showSubmenu(posleft, postop, submenu);,remove method from timer...it will work...

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to stackoverflow, so please be nice :)
however turning to the problem of horizontal jQuery ui menu, the only way I could manage to resolve the problem (refering to [this](http://coderevision.com/how-to-have-a-jquery-ui-menu-displayed-horizontally/)) was to set:

```
#nav li {width: auto; clear: none; float: left}
#nav ul li {width: auto; clear: none; float:none}
```

Comment: so please be nice :) LOLLLLLLLL

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to Mihalis Bagos answer. I have ended up doing the following:

```
<style>
.ui-menu{
   z-index: 1000;
}

#menubar-layout-container > .ui-menu:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

#menubar-layout-container > .ui-menu > .ui-menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-icon{
   display: none;
}
</style>
```

This makes the top level menu horizontal but leaves any sub menus vertical.

I had to remove the icons as this was messing up the layout

There also seems to be a problem with the sub menu positioning.

Comment: Thanks.  Having all submenus horizontal was a bit odd.  This helped quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

changing:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    zoom: 1; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

to:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    zoom: 1; 
    width: auto; 
    float:left; 
 }
```

should start you off.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I was digging into the jQuery UI source code and built upon Rowan's answer which
was closer to what I had been looking for.  Only I needed the carrots as I felt it was important to have a visual indicator 
of possible submenus.  From looking at the source code (both .js and .css) I came up with this that allows the carrot be 
visiable without messing with design (height) and also alowing menu to appear vertical below the parent item.

In the jquery-ui.js do a search to find `$.widget( "ui.menu")` and change postition to:

```
position: {
my: "center top",
at: "center bottom"
}
```

And in your css add:

```
#nav > .ui-menu:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

#nav > .ui-menu > .ui-menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;

    width: auto;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
    padding: 0;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-icon{
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    top: 6px;
}
```

End Result will be a jQuery UI Menu horizontal with sub menus being displayed veriticaly below the parent menu item.

Answer (score 1):

The best option I found is a plugin called **jMenu**.

Main:  http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jmenu 
Demo:  http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jmenu/ 
GitHub:  https://github.com/alpixel/jMenu

Screenshot:
[image: demo menu]

Comment: Could you include something more than some links?  The only useful part of your answer is "plugin called jMenu".

Comment: Your links are all 404

Answer (score 0):

To get a horizontal nav bar with vertical dropdowns, use a combination of a table and unordered lists.

The level 1 items are represented by table cells, subsequent levels are represented by unordered lists.

The positioning of the child menus was a problem. The default is to have them appear directly alongside, but when on a top level item, that was obscuring the subsequent items in the horizontal nav bar. Having them appear below was ok for a single dropdown menu, but if there was a second level beneath, then that 2nd level would obscure the rest of the first. The solution is to have the menu open below and somewhat to the right, see the "position" option in the menu invocation.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #trJMenu td { white-space: nowrap; width: auto; }
  #trJMenu li { white-space: nowrap; width: auto; }
</style>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#trJMenu").menu( { position: { my: "left top", at: "center bottom" } } );          
  });
</script>


<table>
  <tr id='trJMenu'>
    <td>
      <a href='#'>Timesheets</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Labour</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Chargeout Report</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href='#'>Activity Management</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Proposals</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```