# JQUERY horizontal Menu on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have used the following example of the JQUERY UI horizontal Menu:
[How to make jQuery UI nav menu horizontal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944364/how-to-make-jquery-ui-nav-menu-horizontal)
which works great on Chrome
but in IE 9 it looks horrible and it is not horizontal
do you have any idea what I have been missing?

my JQUERY sources:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

my css:

```
#menu li 
{ 
    width: auto;
    clear: none;
    background:blue;
    margin-right:3px;
    margin-left:3px;
    margin-top:2px;
    float: left;
}

.menuIconItem 
{
    cursor:hand;
}

.liMenuItem
{
    background-color:transparent;
}

.menu
{
    border: 0px !important;
    background:D0E1F7 !important;
}
```

my code:

```
<ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li class="liMenuItem" title="1">
    <a onclick="menuItemClicked('1');" class="menuIconItem">
    <img src="1.png" id="img1">
    </a></li>
    <li class="liMenuItem" title="2">
    <a onclick="menuItemClicked('2');" class="menuIconItem">
    <img src="2.png" id="img2">
    </a></li></ul>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

[image: IE demo]please refer the following link for more details,

[Cross browser menu](http://www.newthinktank.com/2011/11/cross-browser-horizontal-menu/)

it tells that for IE you have to make changes to the css file because some stuffs might not work in IE normally,

```
ul.dropdown ul li { 
    display: inline; 
    width: 100%; /* Width depends on the size of containing block */
}
```

try this hope it helps..