# How to create a horizontal JQuery 1.9 Menu?

Tags: jquery

[JQuery UI 1.9](http://jqueryui.com/menu/) has a very handy function to create a menu. However this menu is a vertical menu. Has anyone used JQuery 1.9 to create a horizontal menu ?

**UPDATE**

I added the page

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Item #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li> 

</ul>
```

I added the following code into the css:

.ui-menu:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}

The CSS created a horizontal menu for Item#1 and Profile. However the CSS could not make Ada, Saarland, and Salzburg as a drop down menu of Profile.

Anyone has any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate from [How to make jQuery UI nav menu horizontal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944364/how-to-make-jquery-ui-nav-menu-horizontal)

But you can definitely do it: it is not a jQuery issue, you just need to style the affected elements with CSS, which are the `.ui-menu` and `.ui-menu-item` classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same HTML-syntax (li's and so on) to create a menu and then organize the display by CSS. This is the way I have done it. You could add UI-handling to elements of the menu to provide effects.

Answer (score 0):

According to jquery ui documentation there is no api to make it horizontal.
But you can use some css to make it horizontal easily:

http://coderevision.com/how-to-have-a-jquery-ui-menu-displayed-horizontally/

Comment: The link is broken