# Menu and menuitem orientation issue in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Can anyone suggest me how can I make the below code to display the menu in horizontal view on the top of the page. Currently the below J-query code  displays the menu in the left-hand side of the page in a vertical view but I want the menu items to be in the horizontal view.

Can someone suggest me the change of css link I need to refer or any change in below code?
Ada,adamsville,Addyston and so-on all should lie in a **horizontal view instead of vertical**.

**Note:** To see the look and feel of the below code. Copy it in a test.txt file and save as test.html and open in IE or Firefox browser.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test Menu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script>
            $(function() {
                  $( "#menu" ).menu();
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .ui-menu { 
                 width: 150px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="ui-state-disabled">Aberdeen</li>
            <li>Ada</li>
            <li>Adamsville</li>
            <li>Addyston</li>
            <li>Delphi
                <ul>
                     <li class="ui-state-disabled">Ada</li>
                     <li>Saarland</li>
                     <li>Salzburg an der schnen Donau</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Saarland</li>
            <li>Salzburg
                <ul>
                    <li>Delphi
                         <ul>
                             <li>Ada</li>
                             <li>Saarland</li>
                             <li>Salzburg</li>
                         </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Delphi
                          <ul>
                            <li>Ada</li>
                            <li>Saarland</li>
                            <li>Salzburg</li>
                          </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Perch</li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li class="ui-state-disabled">Amesville</li>
          </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: CSS, add `li{display:inline;}`

Comment: `Note: To see the look and feel of the below code. Copy it in a test.txt file and save as test.html and open in IE or Firefox browser.` Or use jsfiddle.

Comment: @ScriptLearner, Are you catching the hints here?  1) did you see the edit from J Prakash?  See how MUCH easier it is to read your code with good indentation?  2) do you see how jsfiddle works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some menu params you can get this working as horizontal menu

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test Menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).menu({ position: { my: "left top-10", at: "right" } });
    });
    </script>
<style>
    .ui-menu li{ display: inline-block;}
    .ui-menu li ul { 
        top: 100%!important;
        left: 0!important;
    }
    .ui-menu li ul ul { 
        top: 0%!important;
        left: 100%!important;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="ui-state-disabled">Aberdeen</li>
    <li>Ada</li>
    <li>Adamsville</li>
    <li>Addyston</li>
    <li>Delphi
    <ul>
        <li class="ui-state-disabled">Ada</li>
        <li>Saarland</li>
        <li>Salzburg an der schnen Donau</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Saarland</li>
    <li>Salzburg
    <ul>
        <li>Delphi
        <ul>
            <li>Ada</li>
            <li>Saarland</li>
            <li>Salzburg</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Delphi
        <ul>
            <li>Ada</li>
            <li>Saarland</li>
            <li>Salzburg</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Perch</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-disabled">Amesville</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: !important, really?  I know we're all learning, but I recommend brushing up on CSS specificity and why !important has some issues...

Comment: Jquery UI sets the top and left CSS of ul dynamically in the child <ul> .. to overcome that !important is used.. otherwise I would never suggest using !important

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS:

```
li {display: inline-block;}
.ui-menu { width: 80%; }
#menu li ul li {width: 100px; }
#menu li ul {width: 120px; }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MULYL/)

Alternate:

```
.ul-menu {width: 600px; }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion it didnt work out.This is what I added to style.css li {display: inline-block;}
       .ui-menu { width: 100%; }

Comment: Funny, that's where I started...  It depends of course on where the menu is sitting... hmmm I'm using a 27" desktop monitor...

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can add this in your css:

**css**

```
.ui-menu:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    width:100px;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100px;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mzqKa/2/)

or

**css**

```
#menu li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin-right:15px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
#menu li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:'Kreon', serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#385f2d;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#menu li a:hover {
    color:#cd6a00;
    -webkit-transition:All 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:All 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:All 0.5s ease;
}
#menu li a span.ui-icon-carat-1-e {
    float:right;
    position:static;
    margin-top:2px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;  background:url(http://download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png) no-repeat -64px -16px;
}
#menu li ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    padding:5px 0px;
    background:#f0f0f0;
}
#menu li ul li {
    float:none;
    width:200px;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
#menu li ul li a {
    font-size:14px;
}
```

**js**

```
$( "#menu" ).menu({
        position: {
            my:'left top',
            at:'left bottom'
        }
    });
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mzqKa/4/)

First example source [How to make jQuery UI nav menu horizontal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944364/how-to-make-jquery-ui-nav-menu-horizontal)

Second example source [Howto create jquery-ui menu horizontally](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/howto-create-jquery-ui-menu-horizontally)