# C# (MVC) and Bootstrap for dynamic layouts

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, markup

I work with C# (MVC) to generate websites. We use Bootstrap to position elements.

If I wanted to let a page have a toggle to display a menu either vertically or horizontally, what is my best design approach?

If I wasn't using Bootstrap or C# I might produce an XML file with the data to be displayed. The XML would be marked up with with no thought of how it would be displayed.

So it might look like this for example:

```
<page>
    <footer>This most likely will render at bottom of page</footer>
    <menu>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Foo">Foo</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Bar">Bar</a></li>
        </ol>
    </menu>
    <content>Some page content here</content>
    <header>This most likely will render at top of page</header>
</page>
```

...and then maybe use XSLT (along with CSS) to transform that page so visually elements would be positioned as I chose (menu at top, side, bottom, wherever) based upon the selected theme/layout.

Is there a standard way to do allow for dynamic layouts using Bootstrap when working with C# and razor files? Is an @IF statement in my razor file that renders a different row/column layout my best/only choice?

Maybe there is a standard markup so that you can easily switch between different themes with different layouts? Although I don't see this documented if so.

I've spent the last hour Googling this without much luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look on the [various](https://www.producthunt.com/alternatives/wrap-bootstrap) [web sites](https://wrapbootstrap.com) that provide this sort of functionality (some $$ some free) .   I used one on a project last year, and TBH it would have taken a HTML/CSS/js expert 6 months to create all the included features from scratch (and it cost less than $50).

Answer (score 0):

Check Jquery Menus. You can toggle Vertical to Horizontal using css. Refer this post - [How to make jQuery UI nav menu horizontal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944364/how-to-make-jquery-ui-nav-menu-horizontal)

If you want to specifically use Bootstrap then check Bootstrap Navbar. I believe you can use CSS to toggle here as well.

In my opinion, for changing layouts we should always use css. The advantage is, page will not be reloaded if the layout/viewport changes and we do not need to maintain separate codebase. This is why we use responsive webdesign which makes use of css to update the look and feel based on size of the device (4K, desktop, tablet, mobile etc.)

Comment: But the issue is that Bootstrap is tightly coupled to layout. It dictates a row/column layout. I mean you could re-write all of the bootstrap CSS classes to change their behavior, but if you're going to that length it's probably not worth using Bootstrap in the first place.

Comment: Yes. It will depend on a particular use case. Another option may be to create small and independent components and place those based on the layout requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think what I'll end up doing is making one shared View per type of layout:

- ~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
- ~/Views/Shared/_leftMenuLayout.cshtml
- etc

... and then I'll create file "Views/_ViewStart" and in this file set the default shared layout I want used based on the desired layout. ie:

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_leftMenuLayout.cshtml";
```