# How can I get my menu dropdown direction to change at the edge of the viewport?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I would like that when the first element expands down and all children of first element expands to right. What I have done:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.information_menu_root_ul').menu({
    position: {
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'left bottom+2'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.information_menu_item {
  width: 300px;
  }
  
.information_menu_root_ul .ui-menu .ui-menu {
  left: 100% !important;
  top: 0px !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="information_menu_item">Header(for hover)
  <ul class="information_menu_root_ul">
    <li>
      <div class="information_menu_item">Item 1</div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="information_menu_item">Item 2</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="information_menu_item">Item 3</div>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <div class="information_menu_item">Item 4</div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It works fine except one thing. When right border reached than no default flip happened. It's because of left/top override, well I got it. But may be there is some trick or parameter to menu which I didn't see?

Default behavior, to compare:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.information_menu_root_ul').menu();
});
```

```css
.information_menu_item {
  width: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="information_menu_item">Header(for hover)
  <ul class="information_menu_root_ul">
    <li>
      <div class="information_menu_item">Item 1</div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="information_menu_item">Item 2</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="information_menu_item">Item 3</div>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <div class="information_menu_item">Item 4</div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Desired effect should looks like:
[image]

Comment: I see CSS for jQuery 1.12.1, yet 1.13.0 for the library. Should not be a conflict, yet you may not get the same results you expect.

Comment: In my project I use 1.13 for both with same effect, I just use local copy in my project and of stackoverflow I found it only 1.12.1 on cdn. I checked, version doesn't effect in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do, what I want, with less expenses than thought ) Idea that do not touch all children let menu handle it itself, but instead correct first child behavior.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.information_menu_root_ul').menu();
  $('.information_menu_root_ul > li > .ui-menu').addClass('information_menu_first_child');
});
```

```css
.information_menu_root_ul {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #c7e6b3 !important;
    }

.information_menu_item {
  width: 300px;
  }
  
.information_menu_first_child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 101% !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="information_menu_item">Header(for hover)
  <ul class="information_menu_root_ul">
    <li>
      <div class="information_menu_item">Item 1</div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="information_menu_item">Item 2</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="information_menu_item">Item 3</div>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <div class="information_menu_item">Item 4</div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And "information_menu_first_child" class "left and top" attributes allow you to fine tune position for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Please review this example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.information_menu_root_ul').menu({
    position: {
      my: 'right top',
      at: 'left bottom+2'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-menu {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="information_menu_item_wrapper">Header(for hover)
  <ul class="information_menu_root_ul">
    <li>
      <div class="information_menu_item">Item 1</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="information_menu_item">Item 2</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="information_menu_item">Item 3</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="information_menu_item">Item 4</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The `flip` appears to work properly and "Item 3" appears on screen under "Item 2", flipped to the other side.

I was unsure why you had the extra CSS, so I tested without it. If this is not doing what you want, please clarify what goal you are trying to reach. A visual example might also help.

**Update**

You might need a nested Menu.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#menu-top").menu().mouseover(function() {
    $("#menu-drop").show();
  });
  $("#menu-drop").menu({
    position: {
      my: "left top",
      at: "left bottom+2"
    },
    select: function() {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  }).position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "right top",
    of: $("#menu-top")
  }).hide();
});
```

```css
.ui-menu {
  width: 300px;
}

#menu-top.ui-menu .hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="menu-top">
  <li class="top-item">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <ul class="hidden">
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="menu-drop">
  <li>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>Item 4</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Same Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xsdr1La3/46/

This creates a pseudo menu that is positioned to be the Sub-Menu. I found this: [How to make jQuery UI nav menu horizontal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944364/how-to-make-jquery-ui-nav-menu-horizontal) and that helped.

Looking at your image, I am not sure I hit on what you want.

Comment: Hi, that's not exactly what I want. I want like first example in question. First child - direct to bottom with no right offset and all sub-children of first child to right with flip on border reached.

Comment: @DuhVir I am not sure I understand. So the first child, Item 2, should drop out to the right of Item 1. Item 3 and Item 4 should drop down below Item 2?

Comment: I'd add picture of desired effect in question )

Comment: @DuhVir I added an update yet now looking at your image, I may have missed the mark.

Comment: Almost ) Wrong order, first must be up->down, others left->right, but I got the point, I'll try tomorrow edit your variant to match the idea )